# Xpath queries based on given node

Tags: xpath

I have a this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <car>
      <id>0</id>
      <color>green</color>
      <color>red</color>
      <color>yellow</color>
      <vip>
        <user>Trump</user>
        <user>Obama</user>
        <user>Merkel</user>     
      </vip>
   </car>
   <car>
      <id>1</id>
      <color>green</color>
      <color>red</color>
      <color>yellow</color>
      <vip>
        <user>Putinski</user>
        <user>Orlovski</user>
        <user>Idiotski</user>       
      </vip>
   </car>
   <car>
      <id>2</id>
      <color>green</color>
      <color>red</color>
      <color>yellow</color>
      <vip>
        <user>Clooney</user>
        <user>Lopez</user>
        <user>Ford</user>       
      </vip>
   </car>
</catalog>
```

And I am fighting with some simple things:

a) count the "color" nodes from car id 0

b) retrieve Obama's car id

For a) I know how to identify car id 0

```
/catalog/car/id=0
```

gives me a TRUE - so this is the proof I am on the right track. But now how can I continue counting the "color" nodes based on car id 0? The solution postet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694186/get-node-based-on-siblings-value-xpath-query) does not work, as well as the [following-sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath) results in an javax.xml.transformerException. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the `color` nodes in `car` with `id = 0` you can use

```
count(/catalog/car[id="0"]/color)
```

Returns `3`

To get Obama's car `id`:

```
/catalog/car[.//user="Obama"]/id/text()
```

Returns `0`

Comment: Hello Andersson, many thanks for your reply. Indeed your count statement works and is a great help. Your second statement also worked after I replaced " with ' (this was necessary due to my xpath.jar I am using)
Again, great and straight forward help!